# How to Have Google Keep Button in Chrome of Android?

Tags: cyanogenmod, chrome-for-android, google-keep

I would like to add content to my Keep as easily as in Desktop in Android.

Phone: Samsung Galaxy S4 GT-i9506
System: CyanogenMod 13

Comment: Not sure if it's possible even with 3rd-party, but the current quickest way to do that is using *Share* to *Keep*, if that can be counted as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Press Settings icon (three dots at the top-right corner) > Share > Google Keep. After once done it, you will get Google Keep icon directly in Settings > next to Share such that you do not need not go deep again and again

[image]